# Literal expression with <option> tag

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to use literal expression like <%$ Resources:Lang, ddlyes%> within the option tag. I dont want to use any asp tags.

```
<select runat="server" id="select1">
 <option value="1" title="<%$ Resources:Lang, dlyes%>"></option>
</select>
```

it displays only the value,not the name of the tag. how to get and display the name inside option tag.

```
<select runat="server" id="select1">
     <option value="1"><%$ Resources:Lang, dlyes%></option>
    </select>
```

tried this first. but it shows literal expression error.

Comment: I don't understand what the ",ddlyes" is for in your expression builder syntax. The correct syntax of "<%$ ...%>" is "<%$ Expression Prefix: Expression Value %>"

Comment: How want the dropdown list look like? How the value should be displayed in it?

Comment: Are you trying to invent your own inline code syntax? Just typing stuff in the aspx does not work.

Comment: ddlyes is for the word "Yes". Its a language dependent project, so the value for ddlyes is taking from resources->lang file. I ve created the variable resources->lang in cs,and tried to accessing from aspx. For asp dropdown control its working,but for <option> tag,it is not working.